# Python: Converting inches to feet

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding, arithmetic-expressions

I thought if I made the numbers float that it would give me a number with a decimal.

```
height = 65.0 / 12.0
print height
```

What I get back is 5 without the remainder when I use it in a string. Like say:

```
    print "He is %d tall." % height
```

Comment: `In [3]: print 65.0/12.0
5.41666666667`

Comment: Works as expected for me.

Comment: I'm actually using it in a string with %d but all it prints is 5 in the string. I did it like I did above and it worked. So it looks like a dumb question.

Comment: ...`%d` is for integers. Why did you expect anything else?!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to the %-formatting use `%g` to get the decimal places:

```
In [5]: print("He is %g tall." % height)
He is 5.41667 tall.
```

You could also define the number of decimal places (e.g. 2 places) like this `%.2f`:

```
In [13]: print("He is %.2f tall." % height)
He is 5.42 tall.
```

The pythonic way to format, however, would be:

```
In [14]: print("He is {0:.2f} tall.".format(height))
He is 5.42 tall.
```

Here you can find a nice overview: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php

EDIT:

cricket_007 is right: OP is using Python2. Thus the correct syntax would be:

```
print "He is {0:.2f} tall.".format(height)
```

Comment: OP is using Python 2